# Can I prepare PDO statements only once for application?

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

is it possible to prepare all of my statements only once while initiating the PDO and then to use only their handlers? If yes, isn't there some performance impact for the server?

To have them ready in DB and just push the value into placeholders. Meaning as application-wide.

Example:
`$select_user_handler_by_name->execute($user_name);`

Reason: I think it would be better to not prepare the statement every time I want to use it. Doing it at the initialization time only once might save resources later.

Answer (score 1):

> Reason: I think it would be better to not prepare the statement every
>   time I want to use it. Doing it at the initialization time only once
>   might save resources later.

PDO statements are run only once by the engine giving you the optimal speed anyway.

Comment: Thanks but what does it mean? After using the prepared statement once the statement does remain in the DB engine in precompiled form? The statement is not erased/flushed/destructed?